# Converting Local Time To UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm up against an issue storing datetimes as UTC and confused why this does not yield the same result when changing timezones:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013");
MessageBox.Show(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.Local).ToString());
```

I am manually switching my local time zone on the machine between eastern and central.

Central yields `1/1/2013 6:00:00 AM`, and Eastern yields `1/1/2013 5:00:00 AM`.  What am I missing here?  They should be the same regardless of the time zone, correct?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I think you need to read this blog post by Jon Skeet to fully understand issues with UTC / local datetimes: http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: So you are taking the same starting time, associating it to a time zone, the converting it to UTC, and getting different UTC times?  Sounds like it is working.

Comment: I don't get why you want to convert to UTC. How about simply starting in UTC? There is an overload of `DateTime.Parse` that allows you to specify the `Kind`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that the `DateTime` returned by your `DateTime.Parse()` statement doesn't come with a time zone. It's just a date and time that can be in any time zone. When you call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.Local)`, you are telling it which time zone it starts in. So if you start in Central, you will get one answer, whereas if you start in Eastern, you will get an answer that is an hour earlier, UTC. Indeed, this is what your code shows.

Comment: So if I run DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() on Central it's the same as as if I run on Eastern.  How do I create a datetime object that when I convert to universal, it is the same regardless of the time zone???

Comment: @user1174729 - when you say "now" you are talking about an instant in time.  If you said "now" at midnight in your own timezone, it wouldn't be midnight the other.  If you want to construct a datetime that is the same regardless of timezone, you would have to create that in UTC.  There is an constructor that you can pass `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Comment: Yes, what Matt said. The trick is to always work with DateTimes that are in UTC, and then convert them to the user's time zone when displaying them.

Answer (score 10):

There is a `.ToUniversalTime()` method for `DateTime` class

Comment: Same result for: MessageBox.Show(dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString());

Comment: It is right. Btw, same time for CST and EST will indeed differ by an hour in the UTC

Answer (score 2):

This is midnight

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013");
```

Midnight in eastern and central is not the same absolute time.
That is the whole purpose of time zones.

Comment: Yup, this is the right answer. Midnight in one timezone is 5UTC and midnight in the othertimezone is 6UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) :

```
static string LocalTimeToUTC(string timeZone, string localDateTime)
{
    var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime ldt = pattern.Parse(localDateTime).Value;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.InZoneLeniently(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZone]);
    Instant instant = zdt.ToInstant();
    ZonedDateTime utc = instant.InUtc();
    string output = utc.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have trouble with converting to local time to UTC then just remove the last keyword of index and then convert to `UtcDateTime`

```
NewsDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(data.NewsDate.Remove(data.NewsDate.LastIndexOf("IST"))).UtcDateTime;
```

Comment: what??? huh????